# How to bind a calculated value to ng-model field in Angular.js so that I can save the full form details in database using Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, coffeescript

I am new to Angular.JS and don't know how to communicate between Rails and Angular.js. I am creating a form for generating invoices and storing them in database. I am **unable to store calculated data** in the database on form submit.

In below example, I am **calculating polish** using  **calculatePolishPercentage** function.

**Issue 1:** The calculatePolishPercentage is working properly, but I am unable to save this calculated value in the database.

**Issue 2:** How to create dynamic product fields in the invoice form so that I can store multiple products under one invoice?

I don't understand how to store these calculated values to the database on form submit.

I think rails is working fine, the issue is in the form as I am not able to bind calculated values with the form submit function.

bills.js.coffee file:

```
app = angular.module("Invoicing", ["ngResource"])
@BillsCtrl = ($scope, $resource) ->
    Bill = $resource("/invoices/:id", {id: "@id"})
    $scope.currencySymbol = "Rs"
    $scope.invoices = Bill.query()

    Customer = $resource("/users/:id", {id: "@id"})
    $scope.customers = Customer.query()

    $scope.calculatePolishPercentage = (polish) ->
        (polish / 100)

    $scope.createInvoice = ->
       bill = Bill.save($scope.newInvoice)
       $scope.invoices.push(bill)
       $scope.newInvoice = {}
```

bills/index.html.erb

```
<div ng-controller="BillsCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Polish in %age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <form ng-submit="createInvoice()">
                <td><select ng-model="newInvoice.user_id" ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers track by customer.id"></select></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="newInvoice.product"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="newInvoice.description"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newInvoice.polish" value="{{calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}">{{calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Generate Bill"><td>
            </form>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Invoices Controller in Rails:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def index
        @invoices = Invoice.all
        render json: @invoices
    end

    def create
        @invoice = Invoice.create(invoice_params)
        render json: @invoice
    end

    def show
        @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
        render json: @invoice
    end

    private

    def invoice_params
        params.require(:invoice).permit(:user_id, :product, :description, :polish )
    end
end
```

Rails Routes:

```
resources :users
  get 'users/index'
  get 'users/new'
  get 'users/edit'
  get 'users/delete'

  resources :invoices
  get 'bills/index'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for Issue 1:**
Replace this line in your form:

```
<td><input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newInvoice.polish" value="{{calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}">{{calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}</td>
```

With:

```
<td><input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newInvoice.polish" value="{{calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}">{{newInvoice.polish = calculatePolishPercentage(newInvoice.polish}}</td>
```